# Typescript remove item from an array by key containing special character

Tags: angular, typescript

I am stuck in this situation.

I have an array with key `tags[$in]` and I want to delete this item by its key in Angular (Typescript).

I have a code where I was trying to delete this by `delete params?['tags[$in]'];` but this   is error and I cannot use `delete params.tags[$in]` because of special characters in key name and I also cannot use `delete params['tags[$in]']` because params is possibly undefined;

```
listSearch<T = Response<any>>(params?: { [key: string]: any }): Observable<T> {
        if (params?.search == undefined){
            ...
        }
        const paramss = qs.stringify(params, { encode: false });
        return this.http.get<T>(`${this.baseURL}/stores?${paramss}`, {
            headers: this.http_headers,
            withCredentials: true,
            responseType: 'json',
        });
    }
```

variable `params` is:

```
 $limit: 12
 $skip: 0
 status: "active"
 tags[$in]: (555) ["5dcbdd558b435f0505beeaf9", "5dcbdd558b435f0505beeafa", …]
 type: "branch"
 __proto__: Object
```

So what to use in line 3 of code to delete this parameter by its key `tags[$in]` from an array?

Comment: Is your key literally `tags[$in]` or is `$in` dynamic value placeholder?

Comment: It is literally `tags[$in]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[]` to access the key to delete, and check it's existence with [`key in obj`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```js
const params = {
    'tags[$in]': '123',
    'foo': 'bar'
};

console.log('tags[$in]' in params);
console.log(params);

if('tags[$in]' in params) delete params['tags[$in]'];

console.log('tags[$in]' in params);
console.log(params);
```

Edit: Typescript Version. More about this in the TypeScript specification: [4.13 Property Access](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1db4f96fd14fc3de5ae3704e925afd6474cfb8f5/doc/spec.md#4.13)

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key]; // Inferred type is T[K]
}

function removeProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
   delete obj[key]; // Inferred type is T[K]
   return obj;
}

const params: { [key: string]: any } = {
    $limit: 12,
    $skip: 0,
    status: "active",
    "tags[$in]": ["5dcbdd558b435f0505beeaf9", "5dcbdd558b435f0505beeafa"],
    type: "branch"
};

const tags = getProperty(params, 'tags[$in]');
console.log(tags); // => ["5dcbdd558b435f0505beeaf9", "5dcbdd558b435f0505beeafa"] 

const tagsRemoved = removeProperty(params, 'tags[$in]');
console.log(tagsRemoved); // => { "$limit": 12, "$skip": 0, "status": "active", "type": "branch" }
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUBcEMGMGsDyA3ApgJwGYBsD2B3ALlAAtJIAHAZ0JCpgVzSz3wDpZcBbYARwFdU9AJa4AdlWAA2ABwAWGQAYATIsXBIATwpDY6YRUgBadKi5NUR4ZDNHM6bkehin6dNE1GARp-ipPnGIwwmIhAOZGVDqwwtDYRrAk0O6wNugAUOmY-GKpomKgYaiQAAoOOuhaADwAKgA0oADSoKgAHjZiACZUoH6auJigNQB8ABS4XgBWxPW9-sSNAJSgAN7poKCmkPzoBROTANp9ALoA3KAgoACSYpgYpp2gWjqgwj01B43H6QC+mdm5SD5TZmCxlXAVaqzZptDrdOb9QYjcZTGYNPoLZZrDagTqobDFVCgfZHfxnC5gG53NyoR7PIlvIafb44rY7PZTU6-TKBeigCjJaBcGirUCkzTEej6MRhY7EZyaUA-UAAXlW6xxABJsMIuNZiABGZR1DUbTVUeAGYiKE040D0aDbEUAIjgQLQzttOOdMDCVAOmpCx2dxAOzoArJ1YF5Op1w+GZF45ABmcOYRThjNeVCoaCYACcntAEajMbjCaTqfTmfD2dzmGgzuOXo29OIzq87lyJGdvy5vMgT2gftVhWK4MhmlGAvcwoaAHJff7A2JjvPFv3xFRcAS2HgwqMlxueVvB0uAEqgtCPNWmcxoCcYLTTwVz0CL4fLoPrzcSHeoPdcAPC8r1pDcgA)

Comment: When i use this and copy params into new array I got error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.` My code is `const paramsss = params as Array<any>;
        console.log(paramsss);
        if('tags[$in]' in paramsss) delete paramsss['tags[$in]'];`

Comment: Can you paste the result of `console.log(params)` in your question please? There is an `edit` option which allows to update question